# LibQREncode qrcode to BMP

Tags: c++, image, c++11, qr-code, bmp

I'm creating a qrcode with the library [qrencode.h](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/)
This creation is working nice but how would one output the qrcode to a BMP file within c++?
At this very moment i have this code:

```
const char*         szSourceSring = QRCODE_TEXT;
unsigned int    unWidth, x, y, l, n, unWidthAdjusted, unDataBytes;
unsigned char*  pRGBData, *pSourceData, *pDestData;
QRcode*         pQRC;
FILE*           f;
 
if (pQRC = QRcode_encodeString(szSourceSring, 4, QR_ECLEVEL_H, QR_MODE_8, 1))
        {
        unWidth = pQRC->width;
        unWidthAdjusted = unWidth * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER * 3;
        if (unWidthAdjusted % 4)
            unWidthAdjusted = (unWidthAdjusted / 4 + 1) * 4;
        unDataBytes = unWidthAdjusted * unWidth * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER;
 
            // Allocate pixels buffer
 
        if (!(pRGBData = (unsigned char*)malloc(unDataBytes)))
            {
            printf("Out of memory");
            }
           
            // Preset to white
 
        memset(pRGBData, 0xff, unDataBytes);
 
 
            // Prepare bmp headers
 
        BITMAPFILEHEADER kFileHeader;
        kFileHeader.bfType = 0x4D42;  // "BM"
        kFileHeader.bfSize =    sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) +
                                sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) +
                                unDataBytes;
        kFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
        kFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
        kFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) +
                                sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
 
        BITMAPINFOHEADER kInfoHeader;
        kInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        kInfoHeader.biWidth = unWidth * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER;
        kInfoHeader.biHeight = -((int)unWidth * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER);
        kInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        kInfoHeader.biBitCount = 24;
        kInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        kInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
        kInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
        kInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
        kInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
        kInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
 
            // Convert QrCode bits to bmp pixels
 
        pSourceData = pQRC->data;
        for(y = 0; y < unWidth; y++)
        {
            pDestData = pRGBData + unWidthAdjusted * y * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER;
            for(x = 0; x < unWidth; x++)
            {
                if (*pSourceData & 1)
                {
                    for(l = 0; l < OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER; l++)
                    {
                        for(n = 0; n < OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER; n++)
                        {
                            *(pDestData +       n * 3 + unWidthAdjusted * l) =  PIXEL_COLOR_B;
                            *(pDestData + 1 +   n * 3 + unWidthAdjusted * l) =  PIXEL_COLOR_G;
                            *(pDestData + 2 +   n * 3 + unWidthAdjusted * l) =  PIXEL_COLOR_R;
                        }
                    }
                }
                pDestData += 3 * OUT_FILE_PIXEL_PRESCALER;
                pSourceData++;
            }
        }
 
 
            // Output the bmp file
 
        /*if (((f = fopen(OUT_FILE, "r")) != NULL))
            {*/
            f = fopen(OUT_FILE, "wb");
            fwrite(&kFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 14, f);
            fwrite(&kInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 40, f);
            fwrite(pRGBData, sizeof(unsigned char), unDataBytes, f);
           
            fclose(f);
/*          }
        else
            {
            printf("Unable to open file");
            }
*/
            // Free data
 
        free(pRGBData);
        QRcode_free(pQRC);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("NULL returned");
        }
```

But somehow this creates a BMP with corrupt headers. Whenever i'm opening the bmp file it says:

> "BMP Image has unsupported header size"

What am i doing wrong?
And is it possible to save to png instead of BMP?
I have access to the `libPNG` library

Comment: `fwrite` takes two size parameters, which multiplied together gives it the total number of bytes to write.  In your code, `fwrite` is getting the structure size twice (once in a `sizeof` and once as a literal `int`), so `fwrite` ends up attempting to write the squared byte count of each `struct`.  To fix, change these lines to something similar: `fwrite(&kFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, f);`

Comment: @ChristopherOicles I've changed it into your suggestion still getting the unsupported header size..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code example which dumps a 24 bpp bmp file created from a QR-Code.  The error you see is probably not caused by the QR-Code library, but rather something in the bmp file code.

The bmp file created by this example works fine with the image viewer packaged with my Windows 8.1.  If you also do not see the error, you could check for differences in each binary output to pinpoint the problem.  If you want.

This question is tagged "C++" and "C++11", so this example uses the C++ std library for file output, and doesn't use `malloc`.  (But almost equally bad -- I use `new` and `delete` in some container code, where a `std::vector` member is preferred...don't tell anyone).  Also, this example writes each piece of data directly to the file, instead of using a file-sized intermediate buffer, like `pDestData`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// A fake (or "somewhat limited") QR Code data container
struct Qrc {
    int dimsize;          // the width and height
    unsigned char* data;  // buffer which contains the elements
    Qrc() {
        static const unsigned int bin[] = { // encodes an important secret message
            0xfc8b7d7f,0xa801a83,0xd6e54d76,0xaa9eb2ed,0x43ed05db,0xb8786837,0x55555fe0,
            0x5a4c807f,0xcf315c00,0x6e8019ce,0xc7819e0d,0xd4857ba8,0x4ac5e347,0xf6f349ba,
            0xd433ccdd,0x2998361e,0x4453fab3,0x526d9085,0x81f38924,0xb4da0811,0x84b3131a,
            0x9639915e,0x3b74a4ff,0x42aa0c11,0x4127be16,0x1f4350,0xff620296,0xad54de1,
            0xd38c2272,0xa3f76155,0x5366a7ab,0x9bdd2257,0x300d5520,0x85842e7f,0 };
        dimsize = 33;
        data = new unsigned char[dimsize * dimsize];
        auto p = data;
        auto endp = p + dimsize * dimsize;
        for(unsigned int b : bin) {
            for(int i=0; i<32; ++i) {
                if(p == endp) break;
                *(p++) = b & (1 << i) ? 255 : 0;
    }   }   }
    Qrc(const Qrc&) = delete;
    Qrc& operator = (const Qrc&) = delete;
    ~Qrc() { delete [] data; }
};

struct BIH {   // a private definition of BITMAPINFOHEADER
    unsigned int   sz;
    int            width, height;
    unsigned short planes;
    short          bits;
    unsigned int   compress, szimage;
    int            xppm, yppm;
    unsigned int   clrused, clrimp;
};

void SaveBmp(const char* filename, const Qrc& qrc) {
    // Asker's Qrc struct delivered as a pointer, from a C API, but this example doesn't mimic that.
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    if(!ofs) {
        std::cout << "Writing " << filename << " failed\n";
        return;
    }

    const int side_len            = qrc.dimsize;  // width and height of the (square) QR Code
    const int pixel_side_len      = 4; // QRC element's size in the bmp image (in pixels)
    const int bmp_line_bytes      = side_len * pixel_side_len * 3;
    const int bmp_line_pad_bytes  = (4 - bmp_line_bytes % 4) % 4;  // bmp line data padding size
    const int bmp_data_size       = side_len * (bmp_line_bytes + bmp_line_pad_bytes);

    BIH bih = { sizeof(bih) };      
    bih.width = side_len * pixel_side_len;   // element count * element size
    bih.height = -side_len * pixel_side_len; // negative height => data begins at top of image
    bih.planes = 1;
    bih.bits = 24;

    const int header_size = sizeof(bih) + 14;  // size of the bmp file header
    const int filesize    = header_size + bmp_data_size; // size of the whole file

    ofs.write("BM", 2);
    ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&filesize), 4);
    ofs.write("\0\0\0\0", 4);  // 2x 16-bit reserved fields
    ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&header_size), 4);
    ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bih), sizeof(bih));

    // pixel colors, as Blue, Green, Red char-valued triples
    // the terminating null also makes these usable as 32bpp BGRA values, with Alpha always 0.
    static const char fg_color[] = "\0\0\0";
    static const char bg_color[] = "\xff\xff\xff";

    auto pd = qrc.data;

    // send pixel data directly to the bmp file
    // QRC elements are expanded into squares
    // whose sides are "pixel_side_len" in length.
    for(int y=0; y<side_len; ++y) {
        for(int j=0; j<pixel_side_len; ++j) {
            auto pdj = pd;
            for(int x=0; x<side_len; ++x) {
                for(int i=0; i<pixel_side_len; ++i) {
                    // *pdj will be 0 or 255 (from "fake" Qrc)
                    // Using "*pdj & 1" here, just to match asker's code
                    // without knowing why this was done.
                    ofs.write(*pdj & 1 ? fg_color : bg_color, 3);
                }
                ++pdj;
            }
            if(bmp_line_pad_bytes) {
                ofs.write("\0\0\0", bmp_line_pad_bytes);
            }
        }
        pd += side_len;
    }
}

int main() {
    SaveBmp("MyQrCode.bmp", Qrc());
}
```